# Browser dev tools: CSS Grid doesn't align well with RTL

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to align CSS grid in browser devtools with RTL? In browser:

[image]

BUT, In when I inspect element:

[image]

The border from the devtools (F12) doesn't fit to output in the browser.. How to fix that?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
}

.col1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.col2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The dir attribute specifies the text direction of the element's content. `dir` is not for align div.

Comment: Still it's change the layout.. try yourself

Comment: What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: the border (dotted line) fits perfectly with your div in the image, what's exactly the problem? Please indicate clearly on the pictures what's going wrong, it's currently unclear. Also, please precise on which browser does it happen?

Comment: @JonSud the *issue* is with Chrome devtools... you can see that firefox doesn't have this issue... Guess it will be fixed in future versions... :) voting to close this...

Answer (score -1):

remove dir='rtl' from the parent div and add float: left for .col1 and .col2. like below:
.col1 { background:red; height:100px; float: left}
.col2 { background:blue; height:100px; float: left}

Comment: The OP is asking about an issue with the Chrome devtools and CSS Grid Layout. An answer suggesting to use float instead in unhelpful and misguided. Also, The `dir` attribute is not meant to be used for visual effect, it is semantic, but has visual side-effects. Most sites that use it cannot just remove it, nor should it be suggested for them to do so